# Mock a method which takes a function as parameter using GMock

Tags: c++, linux, unit-testing, lambda, googlemock

I have classes as follows.

I am trying to inject dependency but a function is taking a function pointer.

How to set Expectation for function `OnFileLoaded`?

I hope code can clear my question.

```
Class Dependency
{
  void LoadFile()
  {this->SignalFileLoaded();}
  void SignalFileLoaded()
  {
    if (on_file_loaded_){on_file_loaded_();}
  }
private:
std::function<void()>   on_file_loaded_;
}    
//////////////////////
class Test<typename T>
{
 Test()
  {
    obj_dep->OnFileLoaded([this]() {
      SignalFileLoaded();
     });
  }
  void OnFileLoaded(std::function<void()> const &f)
  {on_file_loaded_ = f;}
  void SignalFileLoaded()
  {
    if (on_file_loaded_)
    {
      on_file_loaded_();
    }
  }
  Void LoadFile()
  { this->SignalFileLoaded();}
  void SetDependency(std::shared_ptr<T> obj)
  {  obj_dep = obj;}
private:
std::shared_ptr<T> obj_dep;
std::function<void()>           on_file_loaded_;
}
```

Here is my mocked object with my test

```
MockTest
{
    MockTest();
    MOCK_METHOD1_T(OnFileLoaded,void(std::function<void()>));
    MOCK_METHOD0_T(LoadFile,void());
}
TEST(testing_mock , signal_testing)
{
   std::shared_ptr<MockTest> mocked_test;
   Test<MockTest> testObj;
  //How to set EXPECT_CALL for OnFileLoaded in this scenario
}
```

I dont know how to set expectation for this method. And it is being called during file loading. Which results Uninteresting function call warning.

Comment: `EXPECT_CALL(*mock_test, OnFileLoaded(testing::_)).XXX` ?

Comment: but your `class Test` should take dependency in constructor instead of deferencing null pointer.

Comment: @Jarod42 If i set expectation this way , still GMock give uninteresting function call for OnFileLoaded.